# How to have fine-grained control over some clang-format indentation?

Tags: c++, clang-format

The following is my clang-format file:

```
  BasedOnStyle: LLVM
  PointerAlignment: Left
  UseTab: false
  BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
  ColumnLimit: 120
  BraceWrapping:
    AfterFunction: true
    BeforeCatch: true
    SplitEmptyFunction: false
    SplitEmptyRecord: false
    AfterExternBlock: true
 IndentWidth: 2
 DerivePointerAlignment: false
 NamespaceIndentation: All
 AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
 AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
 AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
```

There are certain options I want such as for the following function:
`extern "C" void foo(unsigned int functionID);`

to be formatted like

```
extern "C" 
void foo(unsigned int functionID);
```

and `void classA::foo(bool openNewFiles)`

to be formatted like

```
void classA::
foo(bool openNewFiles) 
{
  //hello
}
```

Does Clang-format give me fine grain control over this spacing? I can't seem to find a way to do it. What changes in my .clang-format file can enable this?

Comment: These appear to be 2 distinct questions. I would suggest splitting them up into separate questions.

Comment: Clang-tidy can't make all possible code styles that human can think. Usually developers update this open source project to their needs and offer their changes to the upstream.